# Unable to download Xamarin App using iOS10

Tags: ios, xamarin, appcenter, soti

I have Xamarin iOS app and I set the deployment target in the Info.plist to 10.0. We using soti and App Center to distribute our apps to our users. Users using version of iOS10 complaining that they cannot download the apps. Is there something I can do in Xamarin side to fix this issue?

Comment: You need more information than "they cannot download".  Have you checked the device logs?  Have you tried it yourself?  Have you checked with SOTI support?

Comment: Our tester tried it with his iOS 10 device. The App cannot be downloaded in SOTI and App Center using iOS10

Comment: that doesn't really add any useful information

Comment: Our tester tried installing the binary on his iOS10 device using iTunes but he wasn't able to install it.

Comment: again, this is really not helpful.  You should be looking at the device logs, talking to SOTI, etc.  The last update for iOS 10 was three years ago